# if entered value and xml value are same then display first element of xml file

Tags: html, xml, xpath

this is my xml sample:-

```
<products>
    <product_id value="1">
        <tab_id value="351">
            <date value="30-09-1989" />
        </tab_id>
    </product_id>   
    <product_id value="2">
        <tab_id value="352">
            <date value="03-03-1990" />
        </tab_id>
    </product_id>
</products>
```

this is i tried :-

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Less,Grater,Equal</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xml;
        $.get(
        "xml_Converted.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
            );
            function get_list()
            {
                var ename = $('#select').val();
                var xPath = '//*["' + ename + '" = ' +
                            ' //date/@value'  + '"]/../../@value';
                var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }

            $("#result").text(str);
        }
    </script>
        <body>
        <input type="text" id="select">
        <input type="button" value="search">
        <div id="result"></div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

here i want to o/p if user enter date in text box then its match on over xml tree its soud return first element attribut value of xml tree (product_id value)o/p is `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this:

```
var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                  XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
var str = '';
while (thisNode) {
    if (str) {
        str += ', ';
    }
    str += thisNode.textContent;
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
}
```

to this:

```
var node = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var str = node.singleNodeValue ? node.singleNodeValue.textContent : '';
```

should do it.

Comment: There are a few problems with your XPath. I think it should be: `var xPath = '//*["' + ename + '" = date/@value]/../../@value';`

Comment: if both date are same so what for this both date are same then display 1,2

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you saying that it's displaying "1, 2", or that you _want to_ display "1, 2"? If you want to display "1, 2", then you can just revert to your original code (but fix the XPath).

Comment: user enter any of the attribute value of this attribute `<dist_activity value=5,10068,20000>` like 10068 hows set for this xpath

Comment: i want to check less-than condition on date